# how to securely implement fb login using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, web-applications, authentication

I'm implementing facebook login in my webproject, using Jquery. Everything is fine, yet I'm worried about the possible hacks people can try as everything is visible in firebug. I mean, anyone can see what URLs are being accessed in response to facebook requests; data is readily available , app_id being embedded in js file itself. So, I assume I might have been doing things wrongly and so here I am, to get clear about that. So, as per my knowledge, the process of Facebook login works as below:

```
->User Clicks on 'FB Login'
->Request goes to Fb with App ID
->Fb cross checks for App credentials
->Once authorised, it checks for user's credentials
->Asks user to log in if he/she isn't logged in->Returns the requested data by the app for the user
->Calls the call back function and that's where we come back again in scene.
```

In above procedure, what's confusing me is, if a user can see that what data is being passed to what URL in the last step, couldn't he simply call a fake script to that URL and log in maliciously? I know there is an access_token but I'm confused at how to use that access token (or, anything else, out of my knowledge) at the backend to ensure that the coming request is coming only from the callback function on success of Facebook login?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

My personal approach is to use the PHP SDK to check again if the user is logged in: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

You can just add the Facebook ID of the User to an AJAX call, check server side if the User is the correct one at the beginning of your script:

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user && $user === $_GET['fbid']) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I prefer to stay with JS. Not that I don't know PHP, but I like lesser navigation between pages from user's perspective. And btw, adding FB ID of user doesn't guarantee safeguard as any user's FB id is readily available (I guess you know that) and so hacking won't be tough. I'm asking for an approach to make my procedure secure.

Comment: but how do you return the app data? you need a server language in any case - does not have to php though. facebook offers sdks for most famous server languages.

Comment: Ofcourse I am using PHP in the backend. My problem is, I don't want to navigate between several pages just for the sake of Facebook login and that is why I'm reyling on JS. Otherwise, PHP is secure enough for this purpose.. But anyways, I have to do this using JS only.

Comment: JS is basically client side, there´s not much you can do to improve security. in the end it all comes down to the point when you need to get or (especially) store stuff in a database with php. you only need to include the php sdk as mentioned in my answer whenever you need to secure your call.

Comment: Hmm. I guess multiple calls would do. I mean, in first call I send an Ajax request containing user's mail ID. Store that in session variable and send back the same mail id. In response function, I call fb's method to get access token and then match it for if it contains an email id similar to one sent in response to my server. Once the two match, I can call again my server with an ajax request and a true status message, or something like that where I can again ensure that request carries forward only if there is a session variable set...?

Comment: actually, that could work, although it´s a bit more complicated than the solution with php - where you only need to add the same lines to every php file that has to be "secured". and i am not sure if it would really be secure, everything that is client side can be hacked somehow so the user could just grab the response and change it on the fly. server side there is not much he can do, apart from maybe an attack on the server.

Comment: Yeah, but employing server side validation on ajax requests can help (maybe). I'm going to assume the worst scenario and try implementing this. Otherwise, we do have the PHP approach. Thanks for your suggestions :)

Comment: yeah, server side validation on ajax requests is what my answer is about, that´s the only pretty secure way i know :) - you can just put that code in a separate php file and include it at the beginning of every other php file that should be secured.

Comment: You're proposing FB's own validation whereas I'm talking about my own validation. Never mind, I prefer creating code of my own. Thanks for your effort anyways. +1 for that :)